# Multiple datepicker: pass dates from php to view

Tags: codeigniter, date, calendar

currently i using multiple datepicker (http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html). I need to pass dates from MySQL table with PHP (reservations) to calendar and change CSS style for show state.

**occupied** - red
**pending** - yellow
**free** - grey

**preview on another site:** http://www.chata-vysocina.eu/en/rezervace/

Anyone have some tips how to do that?

Thank you, 
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i resolved my problem with following lines.

```
    <script>
var dates = [
    [2013, 12, 24],
    [2013, 12, 25]
];

var today = new Date();
$('#reserve').multiDatesPicker({
firstDay: 1,
numberOfMonths: 4,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
altField: '#dates',
minDate: 0,
beforeShowDay: function (date){
    var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();

    // see if the current date should be highlighted
    for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i)
        if (year == dates[i][0] && month == dates[i][1] - 1 &&  day == dates[i][2])
        return [false, 'booked'];

    return [false];
    }
});
</script>
```